# glibc detected-double free or corruption

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I have the following function which reads a buffer from a serial device, get some tokens and print these tokens every 10 seconds. I want these results to save them in a data.txt which I created in my Desktop. In the first loop I have the results and also I have them in the txt file but the second time I have this error

```
***glibc detected***/home/pi/Desktop/programming/bin/Debug/programming: double free or corruption(top):0x00dbe178 ***
```

I know that the problem is something with the free memory which I have allocated but I do not know where is the problem in my code and how can I fix it.Can anyone help me?

```
int learn_port2(int fd)
{
   int i;
   char buff[260];
   memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
   char nodo[6] = "";
   char temp[6] = "";
   char hr[6] = "";
   char dw[6] = "";
   char vcc[6] = "";
   char* ptr;

   FILE *fp=fdopen(fd,"a+");
   FILE *ft = fopen("/home/pi/Desktop/data.txt","a+");
   time_t now;
   time(&now);

   while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp) != NULL)
   {
    fputs(buff,stdout);
    char *pos = strchr(buff,'N');
    if (pos)
    {

         ptr = strtok(buff, "Nodo_,=:V()");
         i = 0;
       while (ptr != NULL)
         {
          if (i == 0)
             strcat(nodo, ptr); 
          if (i == 2)
             strcat(temp, ptr); 
          if (i == 4)
             strcat(hr, ptr); 
          if (i == 6)
             strcat(dw, ptr); 
          if (i == 8)
             strcat(vcc, ptr);

          ptr = strtok(NULL, "Nodo_,=:V()");
          i++;
         }
       printf("Results: %s, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", nodo, temp, hr, dw, vcc);
       fprintf(ft,"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", nodo, temp, hr, dw, vcc);

         fclose(ft);
      memset(nodo, 0, sizeof(nodo));
      memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
      memset(hr, 0, sizeof(hr));
      memset(dw, 0, sizeof(dw));
      memset(vcc, 0, sizeof(vcc));
      printf("\n");
     }
  }
```

Comment: You should compile in debug and use `gdb`/`valgrind` to track your errors.

Comment: You close ft in your while loop. If the next loop run comes to fprintf(ft, ...) ft will already be closed. May this result in that message=

Comment: @urzeit is correct.  `fclose()` is being called more than once.

Comment: You can make use of [valgrind](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html) to debug your codes

Comment: Are you attempting to modify string literals?

Comment: @urzeit you are right. That's the problem. I passed the FILE *ft inside the while and it works. But I do not know if is a good programming solution in every loop to open and close the txt file

Comment: @dali1985. Why don't you just close that file handle below the loop? If you need to flush the output you may refer to fflush.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately again I have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code doesn't compile (I guess the missing `}` is at the end), but I can point out some problems:

1. you don't nul-terminate `buff` after reading it, so `strchr` and/or `strtok` could go off the end
2. you `strcat` into fixed-size buffers, without checking whether the thing you're copying fits. You could easily write off the end of your buffers here
3. you `fclose(ft)` multiple times. You *must* do this only once, outside the loop

You should fix all three, and post your new *compilable* code if there's still an error.

Comment: you are right. With your notices 1 and 3 I found the solution